# Fix adding to database after refresh php

Tags: php, database

i made a simple web app that can add text to database and also can display it. I have such problem, when i added a text(it is added to database and displayed in browser) and refresh the page, in database previous value of text input is added again even if text input is empty. 
[image: before refresh]after refresh[image: after refresh]

```
<?php

        include 'config.php';

        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                if(strlen(trim($_REQUEST['text'])) > 0) { $conn->query("INSERT INTO Posts (Text_Post,Data) VALUES ('".$_POST['text']."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')"); 
                $value = '';
              }
                        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY Data DESC");
                        $ul = '<ul>';
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        unset($id, $name);
                        $id = $row['ID_Post'];
                        $text = $row['Text_Post'];
                        $data = $row['Data'];
                        $ul .= '<li id="'. $id .'"> '. $text . ' </li>';
                      }
                      $ul .= '</ul>';
                      $lista = $ul;
                $conn->close();
        }
      ?>

      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <title>anonim</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
      <?php 
        include 'config.php';  
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY Data DESC");
                        $ul = '<ul>';
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        unset($id, $name);
                        $id = $row['ID_Post'];
                        $text = $row['Text_Post'];
                        $data = $row['Data'];
                        $ul .= '<li id="'. $id .'"> '. $text . ' </li>';
                      }
                      $ul .= '</ul>';
                      $lista = $ul;
       ?>
        <form name="form" action="" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
          <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add" /> 
          <div id="lista">
          <?php if(isset($lista)){ echo $lista; } ?>  
          </div>
        </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Use CSRF on your form, that will prevent a fake post with a browser refresh.

Comment: i found it : 
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    //Here we parse the form
    if(!isset($_SESSION['csrf']) || $_SESSION['csrf'] !== $_POST['csrf'])
        throw new RuntimeException('CSRF attack');
 
    //Do the rest of the processing here
}
 
//Generate a key, print a form:
$key = sha1(microtime());
$_SESSION['csrf'] = $key;
?>
 
<form action="this.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" />
<!-- Some other form fields you want here, and of course a submit button -->
</form>
but don't understand how to implement it in my code